# GNU MAKE: Quotes when using @echo 'hello' behave different on different machines

Tags: gnu-make, gnu

On my machine `@echo 'hello'` in my makefile prints out 'hello'. Yet on another machine it prints out hello without the quotes.

So `@echo 'hello'` is incorrect on my machine but correct on my colleges.
Yet `@echo hello` works fine on my machine.

This is not just limited to echo, it seems that my machine does not work with quotes yet my colleges does. We have similar machines and are using the same version of make.

This is a problem as we are both trying to use the same makefile, yet I cannot process the file correctly?

Comment: You will have to provide a lot more details than that.  Does it happen with a simple makefile containing just a single rule like `foo: ; @echo 'hello'`?  I find that essentially impossible to believe.  What does `make --version` say on both systems?  To be clear, the correct and only understandable behavior for this makefile is to print `hello` (no quotes).  What does `/bin/sh --version` say on both systems?

Comment: I will try and find some more info. I don't have access to my colleges machine today. We are both running Windows 7 and building from eclipse. I have lots of other make files that work just fine with no quotes around things. The problem is that his makefile has the quotes and it works fine for him and our customers but not me. I thought this might have been an obvious problem to someone in the know, but maybe it is something more obscure. We are using the same version of make. I will see if I get chance to look at this further later today.

Comment: It appears the problem is shell related. My machine is running this in cmd.exe which prints the quotes etc and does not work with the makefile

Comment: Oh.  You're using Windows.  Well, that's much more clear then.  Most likely your version of make is built or configured to use Windows command.com as its shell, and your colleague's make is built or configured to use a UNIX shell (cygwin or mingw or whatever).

Comment: Yes that was the problem, kind of. Shell was set to sh.exe, however it could not find it in the path, so it defaulted to cmd.exe. This also explains a few problems I have had in the past!